# Реализация паттерна Builder v3

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Реализация паттерна Builder (третья часть) + мои первые Junit тесты, до этого я никогда не писал тесты. Ссылки на предыдущие реализации Builder-a: **часть 1**  http://clck.ru/8pke3 и **часть 2**  http://clck.ru/8pkeF

Реализация паттерна:

**1) Абстрактный класс BaseCarBuilder.**

```
abstract class BaseCarBuilder {

    public abstract void buildBody();

    public abstract void buildColor();
}
```

**2) Класс Car.**

```
public class Car {

    enum Color {RED, BLACK, WHITE}

    enum Body {SEDAN, CABRIOLET, LIMOUSINE}

    private Body body;
    private Color color;
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // данный вид сконфигурировала IntelliJ IDEA 12
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "body=" + body +
                ", color=" + color +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**3) Класс CarBuilderDirector.**

```
public class CarBuilderDirector {

    private final BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder;

    public CarBuilderDirector(BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder) {
        this.baseCarBuilder = baseCarBuilder;
    }

    public void construct() {
        this.baseCarBuilder.buildBody();
        this.baseCarBuilder.buildColor();
    }
}
```

**4) Класс VolvoBuilder который наследуется от BaseCarBuilder.**

```
public class VolvoBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    private Car car;

    public VolvoBuilder() {
        car = new Car("Volvo");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildBody() {

        car.setBody(Car.Body.LIMOUSINE);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildColor() {
        car.setColor(Car.Color.BLACK);
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}
```

**5) Класс Client**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CarBuilderDirector director = null;   
        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
        director = new CarBuilderDirector(volvoBuilder);
        director.construct();
        System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar().toString());
    }
}
```

**Ну и на десерт мои первые тесты:**

**1)Класс VolvoBuilderTest**

```
public class VolvoBuilderTest {

    private static Car car;
    private static Car.Body body;
    private static Car.Color color;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {

        car = new Car("Volvo");
        body = Car.Body.LIMOUSINE;
        color = Car.Color.BLACK;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {

        car = null;
        body = null;
        color = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildBody() throws Exception {

        boolean flag = true;

        if (body.equals(Car.Body.LIMOUSINE)) {
            flag = false;
        }
        assertFalse("body false ", flag);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildColor() throws Exception {

        boolean flag = true;

        if (color == Car.Color.BLACK) {
            flag = false;
        }
        assertFalse("body false ", flag);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCar() throws Exception {

        assertNotNull("car != null", car);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCar_1() throws Exception {

        car = null;
        assertNull("car == null", car);
    }
}
```

**2)Класс CarBuilderDirectorTest**

```
public class CarBuilderDirectorTest {

    @Test
    public void testConstruct_1() throws Exception {

        BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder = null;
        assertNull("baseCarBuilder == nuul",baseCarBuilder);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstruct_3() throws Exception {

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
        assertNotNull("volvoBuilder == null", volvoBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это древний code review запрос без контекста

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Код хороший (с парой замечаний). Тесты — в молоко.

  ```
  public class Car {

      // Знай и люби особенности языка, на котором разрабатываешь. Члены класса
      // без явно заданной области видимости автоматически становятся
      // package-private (http://goo.gl/0CcbP).
      //
      // То есть, если кто-то в пределах другого package захочет использовать
      // enum Car.Color или Car.Body, то у него не получится это сделать:
      //
      // [[[
      //    'package.Car.Color' is not public in 'package.Car'.
      //     Cannot be accessed from outside package.
      // ]]]
      //
      // Вы бы столкнулись бы с этим, если бы, например, ваш код был бы
      // расположен в package с названием org.example.car, а ваши тесты —
      // в org.example.car.tests. Подобная naming convention, кстати говоря,
      // используется в Apache Harmony (http://goo.gl/nszow0).
      //
      // Это не столь принципиально в пределах этого небольшого задания — вы
      // могли, например, вообще не указывать спецификатор видимости для *всех*
      // ваших классов (включая тестовые, при условии, что они расположены в
      // том же самом package), здесь намного важнее консистентность. У вас
      // сейчас что-то объявлено как public, а что-то — как package-private, и
      // это не имеет смысла.
      //
      // Лично мне кажется, что эти enum'ы нужно сделать public. То же самое
      // касается и объявления класса BaseCarBuilder (abstract -> public
      // abstract).

      enum Color {RED, BLACK, WHITE}

      enum Body {SEDAN, CABRIOLET, LIMOUSINE}

      private Body body;
      private Color color;
      private String name;

      ...

      // 'this' не нужен.

      public void construct() {
          this.baseCarBuilder.buildBody();
          this.baseCarBuilder.buildColor();
      }
  ```
- Теперь насчет тестов. Перед тем как вообще что-то писать, нужно четко понимать, зачем это делается, и какая задача решается. Мне кажется, что, если вы сейчас попробуете своими словами описать, какую задачу решает написание тестов, то у вас, скорее всего, не получится это сделать.
- Тесты пишутся для того, чтобы:

> - Заспецифицировать желаемое поведение и удостовериться, что написанный код ему соответствует.
> - Иметь возможность убедиться, что при изменении кода его желаемое поведение не изменилось (то есть, вы поменяли код и "ничего не сломалось").
> - Иметь реальный, живой пример использования кода, который дополняет его документацию.
> - Сохранить в функциональном виде информацию о сложных случаях и желаемом поведении в этих сложных случаях (edge case'ах).
> - Дизайн кода исходил из тестов и следовал [принципу YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it), если написание тестов предваряет написание кода.

- Проверьте себя — скольким из этих пунктов, по вашему, сейчас удовлетворяют написанные тесты? Правильный ответ — 0.
- Далее, при написании тестов есть два тривиальных правила:

> - `(1)` Один хороший тест лучше, чем пять плохих.
> - `(2)` Если вы при написании теста не можете сформулировать суть этого теста в терминах "Если ... и ... то ....", то стоит задуматься над тем, не делаете ли вы что-нибудь не так.
> - За примером для `(2)` далеко ходить не нужно: "Если я возьму объект класса `VolvoBuilder` и в произвольном порядке попрошу его создать тип кузова (`buildBody`) и установить цвет машины (`buildColor`), то на выходе я получу машину-лимузин черного цвета."
> - Предложенный способ формулировать суть теста, на самом деле, есть калька с [известного принципа AAA](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert), адаптированная под наш великий и могучий.

- Проверьте себя — что получится, если попробовать в этих терминах сформулировать суть каждого из написанного вами тестов? На самом деле, получится полная чушь, например:

  ```
  // Если в Java объявить локальную переменную-ссылку, указывающую на null,
  // то она будет указывать на null.
  @Test
  public void testConstruct_1() throws Exception {

      BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder = null;
      assertNull("baseCarBuilder == nuul",baseCarBuilder);
  }

  // Если в per-test-class инициализаторе задать переменной значение
  // Color.BLACK, то оно останется таким же и при запуске теста.
  @Test
  public void testBuildColor() throws Exception {

      boolean flag = true;

      if (color == Car.Color.BLACK) {
          flag = false;
      }
      assertFalse("body false ", flag);
  }
  ```
- То есть, все эти тесты, на самом деле, крайне неочевидным способом тестируют особенности языка и тестового фреймворка, а не вашего кода. Здесь нет ни одного теста на реализацию паттерна `Builder`. Предлагаю вам в качестве упражнения написать по одному утверждению вида "Eсли ... то ... " для каждого из тестов, которые вы добавили в V3, чтобы понять, что именно было сделано не так.
- Дальше, есть замечания по технической реализации тестов:

  ```
  // Здесь не нужно использовать @Before, @After, @BeforeClass и @AfterClass.
  // Разберитесь с тем, как работают эти аннотации, и для чего они на самом
  // деле нужны. Начать можно вот с этой статьи: http://goo.gl/aYaoCJ
  // Конкретно в пределах этих тестов вам достаточно просто использовать @Test.
  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {

      car = new Car("Volvo");
      body = Car.Body.LIMOUSINE;
      color = Car.Color.BLACK;
  }

  ...

  // Выкинув за скобки тот факт, что это — неправильный тест, саму проверку
  // можно сделать намного проще и очевиднее:
  // [[[
  //     assertEquals(Car.Body.LIMOUSINE, body)
  // ]]]

          boolean flag = true;

      if (body.equals(Car.Body.LIMOUSINE)) {
          flag = false;
      }

      // Если тест написан хорошо, то 'message' при вызовах assertTrue и
      // assertFalse обычно не нужен. Эти сообщения, особенно, если они коряво
      // написаны, только усложняют понимание теста и требуют постоянной
      // поддержки. Не используйте их без явной необходимости — например, для
      // этих тестов они в принципе не нужны.
      assertFalse("body false ", flag);
  }

  // Постарайтесь давать вашим тестам осмысленные имена. За примерами далеко
  // ходить не нужно — посмотрите, как называют тесты авторы фреймворка junit:
  // http://goo.gl/n0Ne9l
  // В нынешнем варианте именование плохое — например, что проверяет тест с
  // именем 'testConstruct_3', и чем он отличается от 'testConstruct_1'?
  @Test
  public void testConstruct_3() throws Exception {

  ...
  ```
- Едем дальше. Я предлагаю (если у вас все еще остался энтузиазм :) вам оформить reroll V4, в котором выкинуть текущие тесты и написать их заново. Вот утверждения, которые вам предлагается реализовать на JUnit:

> - `(1)` Если я вручную создам объект класса `Car` с именем `"MyCar"`, задав ему белый цвет и тип кузова — седан, то вызов `toString()` для этого объекта вернет мне правильную строчку в ожидаемом формате.
> - `(2)` Если я возьму объект класса `VolvoBuilder` и в произвольном порядке попрошу его создать тип кузова (`buildBody`) и установить цвет машины (`buildColor`), то на выходе я получу машину-лимузин черного цвета.
> - `(3)` Если я возьму объект класса `Director` и передам ему произвольный экземпляр BaseCarBuilder, то вызов `Director.construct()` приведет к тому, что у переданного экземпляра будут в произвольном порядке вызваны методы `buildBody` и `buildCar` (и только они). Этот тест сложнее, чем `(1)` и `(2)`, потому что слово "произвольный" в его формулировке **крайне важно.** Для того, чтобы проверять утверждения такого рода, существует специальный подход под названием mocking. Google вам в помощь, ключевые слова — mocks, mocking, mockito, junit object mocking.
> - `(4)` Есть предложение совместить написание тестов и изменения в коде, чтобы вы смогли [почувствовать прелесть TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). Предлагается следующий тест: "Если я возьму объект класса `VolvoBuilder` и забуду установить тип кузова или цвет машины (или и то, и то), то попытка получить сконструированный объект-машину должна завершиться неудачно". Как вы можете заметить, в вашем коде этой функциональности ее нет, поэтому вы должны будете написать и тест, и новый функционал.
> - Правило для `(4)` очень простое — вам запрещено прикасаться к коду до тех пор, пока у вас не написан тест и его запуск не завершается провалом ("красный тест"). Как только у вас есть  красный тест, вам нужно модифицировать код таким образом, чтобы тест стал зеленым. На этапе работы с кодом вам, соответственно, запрещено прикасаться к тесту. На самом деле, конечно, "запрещено прикасаться" — это слишком строгое ограничение, которое иногда нужно ослаблять, но эту штуку я предлагаю вам попробовать сделать именно с такими правилами.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за такие широкие и полные ответы. Энтузиазм остался, я бы даже сказал, что его стало еще больше !!! Мне нужно чуток времени, что бы выполнить все Ваши задания. На данном этапе, написание тестов для меня - это густой лес и дебри. Постараюсь разобраться.

Comment: Вот моя очередная (четвертая) попытка реализовать паттерн Builder в сочетании с Junit тестами. Ссылка http://clck.ru/8qHt3